# Port Erlang permutation function to Java 8 with lambda expressions and Streams

Tags: java, erlang, java-8

Is it possible to write the following Erlang code only with Java 8 lambda expressions and Java 8 streams?
This is from [List Comprehensions 3.3 Permutations](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html)

```
perms([]) -> [[]];
perms(L)  -> [[H|T] || H <- L, T <- perms(L--[H])].
```

Answer (score 8):

Using a ternary op to replace pattern matching, flatMap to replace multiple generators, and static methods to implement | and -- operations:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static <E> List<E> pipe(E head, List<E> tail) {
        List<E> newList = new ArrayList<>(tail);
        newList.add(0, head);
        return newList;
    }

    public static <E> List<E> subtract(List<E> list, E e) {
        List<E> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        newList.remove(e);
        return newList;
    }

    public static <E> List<List<E>> perms(List<E> l) {
        return l.isEmpty()
                ? Collections.singletonList(Collections.emptyList())
                : l.stream().<List<E>> flatMap(h -> perms(subtract(l, h)).stream().map(t -> pipe(h, t)))
                        .collect(toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "b", "u", "g" });
        System.out.println(perms(list));
    }
}
```

The explicit type specification at `.<List<E>> flatMap(` is only necessary due to inadequate type inference from the Java compiler.

Comment: I wondered whether you could also write this without any custom methods at all.

https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/b32747c99db98ae8206a
Would be cool if the stream API had a skip(Object element) method which could come handy if you want to filter just one particular known element.

Comment: This is pretty darn cool.  Thanks.